# WhatsApp "presence" and "typing" Javascript functions

Tags: javascript, whatsapp, whatsapi

In order to obtain the the status(online/offline) and typing state of an user in whatsApp, I used the `Store.Presence.find( phonenumber+ '@c.us').then(function(r){ console.log(r)})` function after retrieveing the resultng object I always get offline status which is wrong, because I tesitfy that with my phone number.

So what are the recent functions for presence (online/offline) status and typing function in WhatsAPI ?

Comment: `[WhatsAPI] is part of Chat API, a PHP library` so why is your question about javascript??

Comment: @JonasW. I wasn't even aware of that, I learned whatsApp functionality with JS and most of the examples I have seen so far was in JS even in github. Mostly there are JS libraries when its compared with PHP. I connect with WhatsApp Web and directly write the JS code in the console so I can see the immediate result, that was the reason behind of that.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var check = window.setInterval( function() {
        Store.Presence.find( phonenumber + '@c.us' ).then(  function(d) {
            if (d.isOnline) {
                console.log( phonenumber + " is ONLINE" );
                // do something with it
            }
        });
    } , 2000);
```

still working.

Comment: Are you sure that its working, when I test it it doesn't produce any result and says undefined in the console.